# Xamarin WebView not triggering navigation event on Google Drive folder changes

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

I am allowing users to browse on Google Drive through a WebView control on the Xamarin Android platform. I am trying to save the last location they visited. However, when the user clicks on a new folder on the drive page, the navigation events do not fire. On a desktop browser this works perfectly and you can see the new address after navigating. I assume this is due to a client side call from the web page and this implies the actual page address do not really change. Am I missing something or how can I force the navigation event to be triggered? Should I perhaps use another type of control?

If I add simple XAML code to a view like this:

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="LabelCurrentURL" />
        <WebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive" Navigated="WebView_Navigated"></WebView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Then in the code behind file we add the event code:

```
        private void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            LabelCurrentURL.Text = e.Url;
        }
```

When you open a folder on the Google Drive page the event never fires.